# OnPaint method is being call for every child control

Tags: c#, winforms, drawing, onpaint

I've a UserControl (WinForms, .net 2.0), and I've this:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPaint(e);

    var rect = e.ClipRectangle;
    var pen = new Pen(Brushes.LightGray, 1);

    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, rect);
}
```

I basically want to draw a border on the UserControl, but the rectangle is being draw in all the child controls too!
I never read it should be called for every child control, is there a solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the child controls invalidate the parent, causing this method to be fired for each one.

Instead of using e as the parameter (e is going to be whichever control fired the event, child or not) use the control name explicity.

Comment: Do you mean use it as the passed parameter like `(PaintEventArgs UserControl)` or like so `UserControl.Graphics`?

Answer (score 7):

Why are you using `PaintEventArgs.ClipRectangle` to determine the bounds of the rectangle? Try using [`Control.ClientRectangle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.clientrectangle.aspx) instead.